# About the substitution in the integration

Tags: integration

$$\int_0^1 2t \cdot \sqrt{1 + 4t^2}dt$$

I see the answer is $\frac{5\sqrt{5} -1}{6}$ but I'm not sure how we got here. Can someone remind me how to do this? My book gets right to this answer but I'm not sure what steps there were done and I haven't done integration in quite some time. Can someone show me the steps?

Comment: Let $u = 1 + 4t^2$...

Comment: Can you show me the rest @peterwhy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let
$$I = \int 2t \cdot \sqrt{1 + 4t^2}dt = 2\int t \cdot \sqrt{1 + 4t^2}dt$$
Substitute $ u=4 t^{2}+1$  and we get $d u=8 t d t$, thus
$$
I =\frac{1}{4} \int \sqrt{u} d u  =\frac{u^{3 / 2}}{6}+C=\frac{1}{6}\left(4 t^{2}+1\right)^{3 / 2} + C
$$
From Newton-Leibniz Formula, we get
$$
\int_0^1 2t \cdot \sqrt{1 + 4t^2}dt  = \frac{1}{6}\left(4 t^{2}+1\right)^{3 / 2}\mid^{1}_0 =\frac{5\sqrt{5} -1}{6}
$$
As desired.

Answer (score 0):

The goal is to look at what part of the integrand, once taken the derivative of, will give another part of the integrand. Remember that each time we take an integral of something, we need to reverse the process of differentiation. Doing a $u$-substitution allows us to first see where the derivative is, deal with it first, and then proceed quite normally with integration.

There is only really a few things we could consider but I'll save you the trouble of trying things out by saying that the correct substitution is $u = 1+4t^2$. Why? Well because if
$$ u = 1+4t^2 $$
then
$$ \mathrm{d}u= 8t\,\mathrm{d}t = 4 (2t\,\mathrm{d}t). $$
So doing this substitution not only simplifies the argument in the square root to something that can be dealt with, but also gets rid of the pesky $2t$ term which is multiplying it. In addition, when we do a $u$-substitution the limits of the integral change. So, it's pretty easy to see that if $t=1$ then $u=5$ and when $t=0$ then $u=1$. As such, our integral becomes,
\begin{align*} \dfrac{1}{4}\int_1^5 u^{1/2}\,\mathrm{d}u &= \dfrac{1}{4} \left[\dfrac{2u^{3/2}}{3}\right]_1^5 \\  &= \dfrac{5\sqrt{5}-1}{6}. \end{align*}

Answer (score 0):

I provide here another way to approach it for the sake of curiosity.

Let $2t = \sinh(x)$. Based on the identity $\cosh^{2}(x) - \sinh^{2}(x) = 1$ as well as on the fact that $\sinh'(x) = \cosh(x)$,
\begin{align*}
\int_{0}^{1} 2t\sqrt{1 + 4t^{2}}\mathrm{d}t & = \frac{1}{2}\int_{0}^{\ln(2+\sqrt{5})}\sinh(x)\sqrt{1+\sinh^{2}(x)}\cosh(x)\mathrm{d}x\\\\
& = \frac{1}{2}\int_{0}^{\ln(2+\sqrt{5})}\cosh^{2}(x)\sinh(x)\mathrm{d}x\\\\
& = \frac{\cosh^{3}(x)}{6}\Biggr|_{0}^{\ln(2+\sqrt{5})} = \frac{5\sqrt{5} - 1}{6}
\end{align*}

Here I have made use of the definition of $\sinh(x)$ and $\cosh(x)$. Precisely speaking,
\begin{align*}
\begin{cases}
\displaystyle\cosh(x) = \frac{e^{x} + e^{-x}}{2}\\\\
\displaystyle\sinh(x) = \frac{e^{x} - e^{-x}}{2}
\end{cases}
\end{align*}
whence we get that
\begin{align*}
\sinh^{-1}(x) = \ln(x + \sqrt{x^{2}+1})
\end{align*}

This is not the quickest way to solve the proposed integral, but it is indeed an alternative way to approach suchlike problems. Hopefully it contributes!

Answer (score 0):

A common method to try when seeing square root like $\sqrt{a^2+t^2}$: try substituting $t = a\tan\theta$.

Let $t = \frac 12 \tan \theta$, then $dt = \frac12 \sec^2\theta \ d\theta$.

$$\begin{align*}
\int_0^12t\sqrt{1+4t^2}dt
&= \int_0^{\arctan 2} \tan\theta\sqrt{1+\tan^2\theta}\cdot \frac12\sec^2\theta\ d\theta\\
&= \frac12 \int_0^{\arctan 2}\sec^2\theta\cdot (\tan\theta \sec\theta)\ d\theta\\
&= \frac12 \left[\frac{\sec^3\theta}{3}\right]_0^{\arctan 2}\\
&= \frac12\left[\frac{(\sqrt5)^3 - 1^3}3\right]\\
&= \frac{5\sqrt 5 - 1}6
\end{align*}$$

To calculate $\sec^3\left(\arctan 2\right)$, consider a right-angled triangle with opposite side $2$ and adjacent side $1$.

Answer (score 0):

Substitute $u^2=1+4t^2$ and use $u\ du=4t\ dt$ so that the integral becomes
$$\frac{1}{2}\int_1^{\sqrt{5}}u^2\ du.$$